# Convert MongoDB data to json on client side

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, express

I'm trying to convert mongoDB data passed by cookie on my client side from my server.
I'm using Express et React.js.

Cient:

```
export default class Profile extends React.Component {

constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {}
}

componentWillMount(){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(cookie.load('user')))
}

render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Profile</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The console.log return :

```
"j:{\"_id\":\"58e622ac7144862dbb5722f1\",\"password\":\"paswdtest\",\"email\":\"test@test.com\",\"pseudo\":\"testname\",\"__v\":0}"
```

Server:

```
const post = (req, res, next) => {


if(req.body.pseudo && req.body.password) {
        User.authenticate(req.body.pseudo, req.body.password, (error, user) => {
            if(error || !user) {
                var error = new Error('Wrong email or password')
                error.status = 401;
                return next(error);
            }
            else {
                req.session.user = user;
                res.cookie('user', req.session.user)
                return res.redirect('/profile');
          }
     })
   }
   else {
        var error = new Error('Email and password are required');
       error.status = 401;
       return next(error);
   }
}
```

I'm trying to convert with parse and stringlify but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB doesn't return JSON but instead it returns extended JSON called [BSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/).

If your needs are simple then the quickest approach may be to just convert the BSON to JSON in your code.

For your example this would be

**before**

```
"j:{\"_id\":\"58e622ac7144862dbb5722f1\",\"password\":\"paswdtest\",\"email\":\"test@test.com\",\"pseudo\":\"testname\",\"__v\":0}"
```

**after**

```
{"j":{"_id":"58e622ac7144862dbb5722f1","password":"paswdtest","email":"test@test.com","pseudo":"testname","__v":0}}
```